# Java 8 Lambda - Filter collection by another collection

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a `Set<String> usernames`
and `List<Player> players`

I would like to filter out those players that are not in the Set.

I know how to do this in Vanilla pre Java 8

```
List<Player> distinctPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();

for(Player p : players) {
    if(!usernames.contains(p.getUsername()) distinctPlayers.add(p);
}
```

I am trying to write this simple code with a Lambda expression, but I am struggling to get `usernames.contains()` to work in a filter

```
players.stream().filter(!usernames.contains(p -> p.getUsername()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This doesn't compile. *"Cannot resove method getUsername()"*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You've got the lambda expression in the wrong place - the whole of the argument to `filter` should be the lambda expression. In other words, "Given a player `p`, should I filter it or not?"

```
players.stream().filter(p -> !usernames.contains(p.getUsername()))
```

Comment: Bullocks! I knew there was something simple I missed. Thanks! #feelsAshamed

Comment: Hi, I am using excact scenario but, it shows  compilation error "Local variable "usernames" defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

Comment: @vijayakumar: Well presumably you're modifying `usernames` somewhere in the method... it's hard to say anything more without seeing your code. Maybe you should ask a new question (after researching that error message.)