# List containing another list to set using lambda in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, lambda

I have a list containing Persons, each person has a list with his subjects inside.

I need to return a Set containing every subject using lambda, so far i've tried this:

```
list.stream().map(person -> person.getSubjects());
```

But that would get me a List> so i can't use it.

How could i print/get every string in the list of every person using lambdas?

Thanks.

Comment: not quite a duplicate but maybe similar: [Java 8 Lambda - Filter collection by another collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170264)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.stream().map(person -> person.getSubjects().stream());` is not a `List`, it's a `Stream`. If you want a `Set`, do this :

```
list.stream().flatMap(person -> person.getSubjects().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This will create an `HashSet<Subject>`. Note the use of `flatMap` instead of `map` to flatten the lists of subjects into a single stream. If you want another implementation of `Set`, for example `TreeSet`, do the following :

```
list.stream().flatMap(person -> person.getSubjects().stream())
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: `list.stream().map(person -> person.getSubjects()).collect(Collectors.toSet());` Using that would return a Set<ArrayList<String>>, not a Set<String> that is what i need.

Comment: Will this return a Set of Subjects, or will it return a Set of Lists of Subjects?

Comment: One less step in yours, nice.

Comment: @gla3dr thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding of the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Set<Subject> subjects = list.stream()
    .map(person -> person.getSubjects())
    .flatMap(subjects -> subjects.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

flatMap is good for "flattening" nested collections.

Comment: The first map is unnecessary, but +1 because you've shown me I misread the question :)

Comment: Yeah I can see yours is simpler. +1 for you for showing me that :)